# Ehcache configuration with no effect

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, ehcache

I've read many answers and looked at ehcache documentation but I just can't find solution to this problem. Ehache just don't want to work for me.

I'm using spring 4.1.6 RELEASE and hibernate 4.3.5 Final, and I want to enable caching so I don't have to access DB every time.

This is part of my pom.xml:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

This relevant part of hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
```

This is ehcache.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"  updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

<defaultCache
    eternal="false"
    maxElementsInMemory="100"
    timeToIdleSeconds="120"
    timeToLiveSeconds="120"
    diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
</defaultCache>

<cache name="model.entities.User" maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="true" timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600" />

</ehcache>
```

One problem is, if I add maxEntriesLocalHeap property to defaultCache, I get

```
error:    Element <defaultCache> does not allow attribute "maxEntriesLocalHeap".
```

although XSD specifies "maxEntriesLocalHeap" as attribute of defaultCache.
I don't care much about that parameter so I removed it, but it's just strange.
Well, at least I know that SOMETHING :) read ehcache.xml.
I know that also because I get output like this:

```
WARN : org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [model.entities.Role]; using defaults.
```

And there is no User class in this output, so adding last cache tag in ehcache.xml did have some effect.

I must say that I also put this line in every hbm.xml file:

```
<cache usage="read-write" />
```

It all seems to work, I don't get any error, but looking at mysql log file reveals that mysql server is getting same select query with same parameters very frequently although this row was not modified. And that is what I wanted to avoid.

I didn't do anything specific in spring configuration files.
Should I?

Thank you in advance for your help. I'm going crazy about this.

Comment: If XSD allows something and runtime fails with that - you must be looking at/using different versions of the package

Comment: Re: your cache usage - your maxElementsInMemory and     timeToLiveSeconds values are very low and that can cause the behaviour that you see. Try to dump ehcache statistics while running queries

Comment: I don't know what do you mean when you say different versions of package? I'm not really sure how to dump these statistics, and now is really late in my time zone, so I'll leave it for now. I never thought that it would be so difficult to enable caching with hibernate. Thank you for trying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a hurry and I thought that this could work out of the box, without making any changes to code. But it does not.

After few days, when I finally had time to take this serious I have found that I never set cacheable property of Hibernate Query object to true.

Like this:

```
query.setCacheable(true);
```

And thats it. It works now.
There are still some problems with transaction support, but it's important that cache works :)